# Leaflet: Update GeoJson filter?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I would like to populate a GeoJson layer with data and then dynamically filter what features to show.

I have gotten the filter function to work but I do not know how to change the filter and then refresh the layer.

Is there any way I can update the filter after I have added the data?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did this by adding each feature type to a different [LayerGroup](http://leafletjs.com/examples/layers-control.html) based on a property of the feature. e.g.

GeoJSON

```
var data =[
  {
   type: "Feature",
   properties: {
      type: "type1"
   },
   geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [-1.252,52.107]
   }
  },
  {
   type: "Feature",
   properties: {
      type: "type2"
   },
   geometry: {
      type: "Point",
      coordinates: [-2.252,54.107]
   }
  }
];
```

Create the [GeoJSON](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#geojson) Layer

```
//array to store layers for each feature type
var mapLayerGroups = [];

//draw GEOJSON - don't add the GEOJSON layer to the map here
L.geoJson(data, {onEachFeature: onEachFeature})//.addTo(map);

/*
 *for all features create a layerGroup for each feature type and add the feature to the    layerGroup
*/
function onEachFeature(feature, featureLayer) {

    //does layerGroup already exist? if not create it and add to map
    var lg = mapLayerGroups[feature.properties.type];

    if (lg === undefined) {
        lg = new L.layerGroup();
        //add the layer to the map
        lg.addTo(map);
        //store layer
        mapLayerGroups[feature.properties.type] = lg;
    }

    //add the feature to the layer
    lg.addLayer(featureLayer);      
}
```

Then you can call the Leaflet [map.addLayer/removeLayer](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#layergroup) functions e.g.

```
//Show layerGroup with feature of "type1"
showLayer("type1");

/*
* show/hide layerGroup   
*/
function showLayer(id) {
    var lg = mapLayerGroups[id];
    map.addLayer(lg);   
}
function hideLayer(id) {
    var lg = mapLayerGroups[id];
    map.removeLayer(lg);   
}
```

Comment: How do I change the marker icon for each layer Group?

Answer (score 2):

In the [GeoJSON](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/layer/GeoJSON.js) `addData` method, the first check is if the data is a collection of features, in which case the method gets called for each feature.

Then the filter is applied as follows:

```
var options = this.options;
if (options.filter && !options.filter(geojson)) { return; }
```

So if the filter filters out the data when you add it, it does not get stored or remembered anywhere. Changing the filter won't make the data suddenly reappear.

You can keep a reference to the geojson and re-initialize the layer when you change the filter.

Comment: Thanks, does reinitialize layer mean addLayer / removeLayer?

Comment: I suspect you can call `initialize(newgeojson, options)` too, but I haven't tried it out. Removing and adding will work for sure.

Comment: Actually `map.removeLayer(gj)` then `map.addLayer(gj)` doesn't work.

Comment: From documentation -> Note: dynamically changing the filter option will have effect only on newly added data. It will not re-evaluate already included features.

Answer (score 0):

See example below, you have a map and a myBus layer.

```
map.removeLayer(myBus);

...add your data edit something ...

myBus.addTo(map);
```