# Leaflet.js: is it possible to filter geoJSON features by property?

Tags: filter, leaflet

I'm looking around and I see a lot of information about how to show/hide layers.  That's cool, but since I can add arbitrary properties to GeoJSON features, I kind of expect to be able to filter them accordingly.

For instance, if I have features 1, 2 & 3 with these properties:

1. small | red | sweet
2. large | green | sour
3. small | red | hot

How would I filter them by size? Or by color or flavor?

Comment: What are you doing with the geoJSON features?  Creating markers?

Comment: Yeah, I've got markers for daycare centers and they have around 6 properties each. I see that I can add them to layers and toggle the layers, but that seems kind of redundant.  I'd rather just show/hide markers based on their properties.  Is that possible?

Comment: Can you post your code that shows how you're creating your markers?  You could set the geoJSON properties as classes, then use jQuery to hide/show by class, but it's hard to be more specific than that without seeing your code.

Answer (score 7):

Please, see [Using GeoJSON with Leaflet - Leaflet - a JavaScript library for interactive maps](https://leafletjs.com/examples/geojson/).

Yes, you can, just add a filter function like:

```
L.geoJson(someFeatures, {
    filter: function(feature, layer) {
        return feature.properties.show_on_map;
    }
}).addTo(map);
```

Or if you want dynamic updating, there's a great answer in this other SO question:
[Leaflet: Update GeoJson filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148598/leaflet-update-geojson-filter)

Answer (score 1):

I have added the plugin for filtering markers by tags at [Leaflet.tagFilterButton](https://github.com/maydemirx/leaflet-tag-filter-button).

If you add `tags` option to your markers you can filter them by your tags/categories. For example:

```
L.geoJson(jsonObject, {
    pointToLayer: function(feature, latlng) {
        L.marker(latlng, {
            tags: ['small', 'red', 'sweet']
        });
    }
}).addTo( map );

L.control.tagFilterButton({
    data: ['small', 'red', 'sweet']
}).addTo( map );
```