# How to filter TopoJSON features by property in Leaflet.js?

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson, topojson

I need to color countries on a map depending on a some value (number of content items for a country). If that value is 0 (null), the respective country should not be coloured/displayed.

In terms of Leaflet.js, this means, I have a GeoJSON file containing a feature for each country of the world. However, the feature is only rendered (added to map) if the number of content items is greater than 0. When using GeoJSON input file, this works already similar to the answer to [Leaflet.js: is it possible to filter geoJSON features by property?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21974597)

This is the snippet for GeoJSON:

```
var mapLayer = L.geoJson(world, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
    return getContentItems(feature.properties.ISO2, "count");
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var contentCount = getContentItems(feature.properties.ISO2, "count");
    if (contentCount) {
      layer.setStyle({
        'weight': 1,
        'fillOpacity': .75,
        'fillColor': "#0077c8", // Actually a function depending on contentCount
        'opacity': .75,
        'color': "#0077c8"
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Now, the GeoJSON file is a whopping 11 MB large due to details on the map. I learned about TopoJSON, which is pretty awesome since the source file is now less than 2 MB with the same grade of detail. I also managed to get the TopoJSON data to be displayed on the map, however, I can't figure out, how to apply the filter.

Here's my current snippet for adding the TopoJSON layer:

```
L.TopoJSON = L.GeoJSON.extend({
  addData: function(jsonData) {
    if (jsonData.type === "Topology") {
      for (key in jsonData.objects) {
        geojson = topojson.feature(jsonData, jsonData.objects[key]);
        L.GeoJSON.prototype.addData.call(this, geojson);
      }
    }
    else {
      L.GeoJSON.prototype.addData.call(this, jsonData);
    }
  }
});

var topoLayer = new L.TopoJSON();
$.getJSON('scripts/world.topo.json')
  .done(addTopoData);

function addTopoData(topoData) {
  topoLayer.addData(topoData);
  topoLayer.addTo(map);
  topoLayer.eachLayer(handleLayer);
}

function handleLayer(layer) {
  layer.setStyle({'opacity': 0}); // Too late.
}
```

I tried to add the filter function to the GeoJSON extension within the TopoJSON declaration without luck. The handleLayer() function is to late, I think, the features have already been added.

***EDIT:***
I am able to remove a layer, if the content count is 0 by changing the handleLayer() function to

```
function handleLayer(layer) {
  var contentCount = getContentItems(layer.feature.properties.ISO2, "count");
  if (contentCount == 0) {
    map.removeLayer(layer);
  }
}
```

For performance purposes, I would however like to filter the features before being drawn. I am just stuck now where the filter function needs to be added.

Comment: I would try and put the filter in the call to L.TopoJSON (as it inherits of L.GeoJSON). You can read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4152931/javascript-inheritance-call-super-constructor-or-use-prototype-chain too

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing me the way. I went down that road and found the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some deep Javascript reading about inheritance just as suggested by FranceImage, I found the solution I was looking for myself. Instead of just creating a new TopoJSON object with `var topoLayer = new L.TopoJSON();`, I am able to pass the custom filter functions as options:

```
var topoLayer = new L.TopoJSON(null, {
  filter: function(feature, layer) {
  return getNN(feature.properties.ISO2, "check");
  },
  onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {
    var contentCount = getContentItems(feature.properties.ISO2, "count");
    if (contentCount) {
      layer.setStyle({
        'weight': 1,
        'fillOpacity': .75,
        'fillColor': "#0077c8",
        'opacity': .75,
        'color': "#0077c8"
      });
    }
  }
});
```

No need to remove layers with the handleLayers function.