# Leaflet Change icon for layerGroup

Tags: leaflet

I'm using the solution from the following post: [Leaflet: Update GeoJson filter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16148598/leaflet-update-geojson-filter)

I can't figure out how to change the marker icon based on the layerGroup. Any tips or ideas? I've used pointsToLayer but it duplicates my points instead of replacing the default icon.

My ultimate goal is to have different marker icon colors based on a feature property with the ability to filter by the layerGroup. Thank you!